# How to reset pgadmin master password and servers

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am learning to program and as I was inexperienced and a bit overwhelmed I lost my master password. I've tried to reset the master password a couple of times but I haven't been able to gain access to the default server. Is there a way to disconnect or reset that server? I have also been having issues with some other servers I created where I am unable to delete them as it says that they are still being used.

I've tried the reset password button and to look online but I haven't been able to find any solution.